# Kivy make a scrollable popup with a static button without using kv file

Tags: kivy

I wonder if I could make a popup consist of scrollable (label) popup with a static button without using kv file.

I have come across this website:
http://enricorossi.org/blog/2014/python_kivy_scrollable_popup_and_static_button/
However, in this example, the author was using kv file.

Another example would be:
http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@k@i@Kivy-1.8.0@examples@widgets@scrollview.py/6/kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView
However, in this example, the author was using gridlayout and button as the input.

So what I want is a popup with:
1. Label that can be scrolled
2. Button to close the popup.

I know how to do the button to close the popup, but I am stuck with the label since it cannot be scrolled. I am trying not to use any of the open source kivy that is I am trying to use the function provided in kivy itself.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with a [ScrollView](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/scrollview.py)? Maybe, also, the [ScrollableLabel](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Scrollable-Label).

Comment: Anything done in a kv file can be done without one - ultimately it's all turned into python anyway.